# Google Map with Spring Rest Service

Tags: angularjs, spring, google-maps, spring-rest

I never used Google API in my web project but now it's time to use so have no idea how to integrate it. I read so many tutorial but for beginner like me its quite tough to understand those tutorial. I have the following requirements:

1) I have spring rest service ready which will send the JSON data having the information

```
[
{
longitude:"some value"
lattitude:"some value"
}
...
]
```

I want to plot all the JSON data to the google map.

2) Also I want to capture the current location of the user and then want to navigate the user from current location to the location send by the server.

I don't have any idea how to start this in my angular application, at least I want few good resource so that I can read and can obtain this result.

Answer (score 0):

After so many tutorial ,this is what I got :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COWhg09NCu4